# How to handle multiple HTTP methods in the same Rails controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I want to support both GET and POST methods on the same URL. How would I go about handling that in a rails controller action?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can check if it was a post using request.post?

```
if request.post?
  #handle posts
else
  #handle gets
end
```

To get your routes to work:

```
resources :photos do
  member do
    get 'preview'
    post 'preview'
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry to dig this up but - is sharing the same route for two verbs somehow a bad practice?

Comment: I think it can be. Or it can hint that your design is a bit poor

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida IMO it's not a bad practice if used when it makes sense to do so.

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida we can see this in Rails default resourceful routing. `#show`, `#update` and `#destroy` all use `/models/:id` with `GET`, `PATCH` and `DELETE` respectively. Same with `#index` and `#create`

Comment: ```Routing both GET and POST requests to a single action has security implications.``` Quote from [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 9):

Here's another way. I included example code for responding with 405 for unsupported methods and showing supported methods when the OPTIONS method is used on the URL.

In `app/controllers/foo/bar_controller.rb`

```
before_action :verify_request_type

def my_action
  case request.method_symbol
  when :get
    ...
  when :post
    ...
  when :patch
    ...
  when :options
    # Header will contain a comma-separated list of methods that are supported for the resource.
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = allowed_methods.map { |sym| sym.to_s.upcase }.join(', ')
    head :ok
  end
end

private

def verify_request_type
  unless allowed_methods.include?(request.method_symbol)
    head :method_not_allowed # 405
  end
end

def allowed_methods
  %i(get post patch options)
end
```

In `config/routes.rb`

```
match '/foo/bar', to: 'foo/bar#my_action', via: :all
```

Comment: The routes part helped me configure things how I wanted them. Thanks!

Comment: As of Rails 5 (maybe even 4) the via: :all flag doesn't work anymore.  Instead, it just sets your route to respond to a (non-existent) "ANY" HTTP method. Should do via: [:get, :post, :put, :delete] now

Answer (score 8):

Just need to use this, to use only get and post in the same route

```
resources :articles do
  member do
    match 'action_do-you_want', via: [:get, :post]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
match '/posts/multiple_action', to: 'posts#multiple_action', via: [:create, :patch, :get, :options]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say, the best way is to create separate actions in the controller and state them in routes.

```
# config/routes.rb
...
get '/my_action' => 'my#my_action_get'
post '/my_action' => 'my#my_action_post'
...

# app/controllers/my_controller.rb
...
def my_action_get
  # do stuff like listing smth
end

def my_action_post
  # do other stuff
end
```

In fact, the same logic is used by Rails by default: `index` and `create` actions are both called by requests sent to the same paths (e.g. `/articles`), however, they have different request methods: `GET /articles` request is redirected to the `index` action and lists all articles, and `POST /articles` is redirected to the `create` action and creates a new article.

Comment: agreed on this; I would say that having a Rails action respond to multiple http verbs is a VERY bad practice. One possible exception might patch / put but get / post?Seriously?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

In routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post '/posts', to: 'posts#create'
  get '/posts', to: 'posts#list_all'
end
```

In posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        new_post = Post.create( content: params[:content], user_id: params[:user_id] )
        render json: { post: new_post }
    end

    def list_all
        request = Post.all
        render json: { all_posts: request }
    end
end
```

So each action is referred to a different function