# How to send form data to #index with post instead of #create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have resource route setup:

```
resources :events
```

For one form, I'd like to send data to `#index` action with `:post` method. 
How can I do this?

I tried `<%= form_tag url_for(controller: 'events', action: 'index'), method: :post`, but it still goes to `#create`

Comment: take a look this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5583794/1297435

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that, and what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't with this routes.

Long answer:
When using `resources :events` following routes get defined for you:

```
GET     /events     events#index
GET     /events/new     events#new
POST    /events     events#create 
GET     /events/:id     events#show
GET     /events/:id/edit    events#edit
PATCH/PUT   /events/:id     events#update   
DELETE  /events/:id     events#destroy
```

Therefore `index` action isn't accessible by `POST` request.

And trying to do so (with f.e. custom routes together with `resources :events`) will make `create` action on post inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

The moment you use

> method: :post

That means your invoking the create method in your controller, You cannot achieve that. Just like @Esse has shown you the routes.
Please read and understand routes on rails guides, it will save you a lot of time debugging, and headache.